Python script using Tableau_api_lib package changing the user quota to "server limit" when trying to changing the storage_quota of a site
I have written a python script using Tableau_api_lib package.
#Importing tableau connection package
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection

#configuring our environment and providing PAT credentials to sign for the "Site_name" site

tableau_config = {
'tableau_UAT': {
'server': 'https://Server info',
'api_version': '3.21',
'personal_access_token_name': 'Personal access token name',
'personal_access_token_secret': 'Personal access token value',
'site_name': 'siteName',
'site_url': 'SiteURL'

    }

}

#connect to Tableau server

Tab_connection = TableauServerConnection(config_json=tableau_config, env='tableau_UAT')

#Signing to server.
response = Tab_connection.sign_in()

#querying the site and store the json
site_json = Tab_connection.query_site().json()

#extracting the site id
site_id = site_json['site']['id']


#updating the site storage.
check = Tab_connection.update_site(site_id=site_id,storage_quota=2000)

# Sign out or disconnect from tableau server.***
res2 = Tab_connection.sign_out()

The above script was running fine for few days but all of sudden it changes the user quota to server limit.I don't what went wrong.
So I tried to change the user quota as well along with storage quota, you can see the below script.
#Importing tableau connevtion package 
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection

# configuring our environment and providing PAT credentials to sign for the "SiteName" site
tableau_config = {
'tableau_UAT': {
'server': 'https://Server info',
'api_version': '3.21',
'personal_access_token_name': 'Personal access token name',
'personal_access_token_secret': 'Personal access token value',
'site_name': 'siteName',
'site_url': 'SiteURL'

    }

}


# connect to Tableau server

Tab_connection = TableauServerConnection(config_json=tableau_config, env='tableau_UAT')

#Signing to server. 
response = Tab_connection.sign_in()

#Querying the json() of the site
site_json = Tab_connection.query_site().json() 

#Extracting the site id.
site_id = site_json['site']['id']

#Updateing the site storage, user quota,creator_quota, explorer quota and viewer quota.
check2 =       Tab_connection.update_site(site_id=site_id,storage_quota=2000,user_quota=2,tier_creator_capacity=0,tier_explorer_capacity=0,tier_viewer_capacity=2)

print(check2)

# Sign out or disconnect from tableau server.
res2 = Tab_connection.sign_out()

but its also not working it returns 400 code.
I need to find what cause this issue and a solution to this would be a big help.
I have been working with a server which has more the 200 sites
please pour your thoughts and help me .
Thank You!
